# Equation number is not coming in align and split

Tags: equations, align, split

I am using align and split in the following way, but equation number is not coming :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Equation \eqref{eqn1} shows

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\hat{\beta_{kjt}} = \alpha_{0k} + \varepsilon_{kjt} \nonumber\\ 
&where,\ T_{kjt^\prime} = 1\quad if\ t^\prime = t  
\end{split}
\label{eqn1}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What's the use of `split` nested  in `align`?

Comment: @Bernard look at the vertical alignment of the equation number. With `split` you get one number vertically centred, with `\nonumber` you get the equation number just behind one line.

Comment: @Skillmon: Isn't it just as fine (and more natural) to use use split within `equation`?

Comment: @Bernard It is (see my answer). But you might use several `split`s in an `align` whether it's good practise or not. Also you might use one `split` in one equation and type more without inside `align`. Whether that's desirable is in the users opinion, not mine, and there is at least this one valid reason to use `split`.

Answer (score 5):

It's no wonder that there is no equation number if you suppress it with `\nonumber`. If you remove that, everything works fine. Additionally you should wrap "where" and "if" in a `\text` so it gets displayed as just that. Also you shouldn't start the equation as a new paragraph (no empty lines inbetween) and as egreg mentions, you might use another environment than `align` (like `equation`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Equation \eqref{eqn1} shows
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\hat{\beta_{kjt}} = \alpha_{0k} + \varepsilon_{kjt} \\ 
&\text{where},\ T_{kjt^\prime} = 1\quad \text{if}\ t^\prime = t  
\end{split}
\label{eqn1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The `split`-environment is only numbered once inside `align` no matter how many rows you use.

Comment: Also, using `align` for a single equation is discouraged. And “if” should be wrapped in `\text`, too.

Comment: Just an addition, I'd probably write the where part as `\text{where , $T_{kjt'} = 1$ if $t' = t$}`, because semantically the whole thing is the where comment, not just the text parts. Also note I changed `^\prime` to `'` because `'=^\prime` in math mode (plus more)